# Prove $\{\varnothing \} \neq \varnothing$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know this statement

$$\{\varnothing \} \neq \varnothing$$

is true because { $\varnothing $} $\subsetneq \varnothing$ since $ \varnothing \notin \varnothing $. Is this true?

Comment: Latex touch: Prefer varnothing to emptyset which looks a little too skinny.

Comment: @JeanMarie I never noticed that until I saw your comment. I'll never use emptyset again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a correct proof of the statement. Denote by $\text{card}\,A$ the number of elements in a finite set $A$. We have
$$
\text{card}\, \{\emptyset\} = 1, \quad \text{card}\, \emptyset = 0
$$
and
$$
1 \not = 0.
$$
Therefore, because equal sets contain the same number of element, $\{\emptyset\} \not = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 8):

The set consists of exactly one set, namely the null set.  So it is not empty; i.e. it is not the null set.

Comment: The null set indicates there is 1 element in there, thus it can't be empty.

Comment: And so, this set with one element cannot be a subset of the null set (which is a set with no elements).  I think your statement mixes the idea of "sets" with the idea of a "non-set."  (The English is somewhat imprecise.)

Answer (score 2):

Since the other answers give the other things I would have said, here's the third way to think about it I would list:

In your title, the first object (on the left) is a set consisting of elements which are themselves sets. The elements, of which there is only one, are all the empty sets.

The second object is a set which, by definition, consists of nothing.

EDIT: I just thought of this option as well. Since the empty set is the set of nothing, we may write $\varnothing=\{\;\}$. Then the answer is obvious.